# event listener in javascript not firing except for when the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I am trying this:

```js
//this represents all of the select tags on the page
var select = document.getElementsByTagName("select");

//Listener for when the option changes
select.addEventListener("change", hi(), false);

function hi() {
  alert("hi");
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
</select>
```

but the event listener does not seem to be working, in jsfiddle it works when the page loads, but not when I change the option...

Comment: Listeners would fire fine, if you just had attached them to somewhere else than a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which is what is returned from [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName). Notice also johnnycardy's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the brackets from the function name:

```
select.addEventListener("change", hi, false);
```

You're calling the function and attaching its result, instead of attaching the function itself.

Edit: Also, as Teemu points out, you're trying to attach to a collection instead of an individual `select` item. Try `var select = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];` - or better still, use `getElementById`.